# IPython bug: python generator fails when global variable is referenced

Tags: python, generator

Is it possible to reference a global variable in a generator expression under IPython.embed()?

```
> ipython bug.py 
Python 3.8.10 (default, Mar 15 2022, 12:22:08) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for 
more information
IPython 7.29.0 -- An enhanced Interactive 
Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: data = list(range(17))

In [2]: modulus = 3

In [3]: data1 = list([x for x in data if x % 
modulus == 0])
---------------------------------------------- 
-----------------------------
NameError                                 
Traceback (most recent call last)
/local/src/bug.py in 
<module>
----> 1 data1 = list([x for x in data if x % 
modulus == 0])

/local/src/bug.py in <listcomp>(.0)
----> 1 data1 = list([x for x in data if x % 
modulus == 0])

NameError: name 'modulus' is not defined
```

bug.py has this:

```
import IPython
IPython.embed()
```

This is a bug in IPython.embed(). As commenters below also point out this works fine in regular prompt.

See also:
https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/136

Workaround:

```
globals().update(locals())
```

[Post was heavily edited and explains disconnect with comments.]

Comment: The code you've pasted works just fine. The value of `data1` ends up being `[0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15]`.

Comment: Is there a traceback which can be posted?  The posted code works just fine.

Comment: I suspect you have a typo in the real code.

Comment: The posted code works just as you expected it to.  Try copy/pasting from your post into your interpreter.

Comment: Is your actual code located in the body of a class definition, by any chance?  Variable scoping works a bit strangely there...

Comment: I was running under IPython.embed(). This is a bug in that module. No typo though.

Comment: correct, & I have reproduced this error meself.

Comment: I've cast a reopen vote as necessitated.